# Positioning images with FloatLayout

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

This is driving me insane.  I'm trying to position an image to the top of the main window with FloatLayout.  Below is a simplified example.

It seems that a button is fine, but an image defaults to a 100x100 square (yes, I think I've read that somewhere) and the top bounding box of the image is at the top of the screen, not the image.

How can I force the image (top of the rectangle) to the top of the window like the button is?

[Screen_showing example_button_and_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se2QC.png)

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')

class MyApp(App):

    def setOrientation(self, orient):
        """"""
        self.orient = orient

    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.setOrientation(orient="vertical")
    app.run()


<FloatLayout>:
    Image:
        source: 'image_400x90.png'
        pos_hint: {'left':1, 'top':1}
        size_hint: None, None
        allow_stretch: False
        keep_ratio: True

    Button:
        font_size: 30
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
        text: "TopRight"
        pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':1}
```

Answer (score 1):

That happend because the Image is a Widget and "the real image" (the picture) is a texture of that Widget, and *by default, the image is centered and fits inside the widget bounding box. If you don’t want that, you can set allow_stretch to True and keep_ratio to False.* ([docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#alignment))

For understand that you can add a canvas with a rectangle in the Image Widget like this:

```
Image:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        source: 'dog.jpg'
        pos_hint: {'left':1, 'top':1}
        size_hint: None, None
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
```

And then you can see why the image doesn't do what you want

[image]

another pic (*the image(texture) is centered and fits inside the widget*):

[image]

One thing you can do is set allow_stretch: True and keep_ratio: False
This is the result: (set the size with size_hint)

[image]

Comment: Can I somehow choose the in-boundary-alignment? So that the texture is topleft for example and not centered (keepratio)

Answer (score 0):

Favcau gives one solution above (and thanks), but I have found what I think is more obvious.  All it needs is to have the size defined in the kv file.

```
Image:
    id: image2
    source: 'image_400x90.jpg'
    pos_hint: {'left':1, 'top':1}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 90
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: False
```